# I'm having trouble accessing my Plesk Panel on the remote server after Node.Js installation

Tags: web-hosting, apache, server, plesk, node-js

I'm having trouble accessing my Plesk Panel on the remote server.

I used Apache Web Server in Plesk Panel. But for an application development I had to use Node.Js. So I searched Plesk official website how to do it and just installed Node.Js and NPM server from Plesk admin panel. After confirming the install, I saw the install progress bar and it never went away. I've waited over a few days to finish this process bar.

The problem is that I can never access the Plesk login panel again (port 8443/8880 is closed automatically) and I can't even access the login page. HTTP or HTTPS requests return "Unable to connect" message.

However, everything except the Plesk Panel login page (i.e. webpages, emails, MySQL database) works fine.

I've tried accessing the server to open the port with SSH by the admin account, but it's being rejected by server. (I've tested FTP access from the admin account, but it's also denied). Thus, I cannot restart the server again. I cannot see logs, I cannot edit htaccess files, or stop any process, change firewall setting, etc.

I can only access the server using SSH and FTP by standard user accounts, but they don't have the required permission to make any changes.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It appears you asked this on several Stack Exchange sites, including [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1718257/having-trouble-accessing-and-regaining-access-to-plesk-admin-panel-on-the-remote), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014297/regaining-access-to-my-plesk-admin-panel-on-ports-8443-8880), and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1099562/im-having-trouble-accessing-my-plesk-panel-on-the-remote-server-after-node-js-i). In the future...

Comment: ...please do not [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) questions. Either flag them and ask for a moderator to migrate them to a different site, or delete them first and then post them.

Comment: In regards to your issue, and also based on the extra details in your post on Stack Overflow, if you can only SSH into website accounts and not admin, then it sounds like you'll need to re-image the server. You'll want to backup each account before you do so of course. I'm afraid there's nothing that we can do to help in regards to that. You could perhaps try asking over at [Plesk's forum](https://talk.plesk.com/) though.